# React native moving a button to child compoenent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-swiper` to a build main UI of my app and need to figure out to add button to swipe screen from child components.

Below code works(Tapping `Previous Screen` will swipe screen to Screen 2) but I need to find a way to move `Previous Screen` text into `<ScreenThree />` component.

**How do I move `<Text onPress={() => this.refs.swiper.scrollBy(-1)} >Previous Screen</Text>` into `<ScreenThree />` component?**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import ScreenThree from './components/ScreenThree';

class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={1}
        ref='swiper'>
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <ScreenThree />
          <Text onPress={() => this.refs.swiper.scrollBy(-1)} >Previous Screen</Text>
        </View>
      </Swiper>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})


export default Home
```

Comment: Not a react native dev, but couldn't you do this:`<ScreenThree onPress={() => this.refs.swiper.scrollBy(-1)} />` and then in the `ScreenThree` component, have a Text field that calls the `onPress` prop from the Text `onPress` event?

Comment: @RickJolly Thank you for the response. Would you mind giving me a sample code for calling `onPress` prop from the child component? :)

Comment: In the ScreenThree render, try: `<Text onPress={this.props.onPress}>Previous Screen</Text>`

Comment: @RickJolly Thank you! that works! One more question, what if I want to move it to another child of `<ScreenThree />`?

Comment: Just keep passing it down. `<ComponentInScreenThree onClick={this.props.onClick} />` or to pass all props down in shorthand `<ComponentInScreenThree {...this.props} />`

Comment: Cool. I'm glad that worked. Posted the full answer in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={1}
        ref='swiper'>
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <ScreenThree onPress={() => this.refs.swiper.scrollBy(-1)}/>
        </View>
      </Swiper>
    )
  }
}

class ScreenThree extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text onPress={this.props.onPress}>Previous Screen</Text>
    )
  }
}
```